# Bootstrap is not working in angularjs 4 project

Tags: angular

I am getting below error in Console:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/bootstrap/dist/css
/bootstrap.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported 
stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled. webpack-
internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:3857 Angular is running in the 
development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode. 
localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/bootstrap
/dist/css/bootstrap.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a 
supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Below is the code that I use to add Bootstrap:

```
npm install bootstrap@4.0.0 --save
```

and then I add the path of bootstrap.css file:

`path(/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css)`

in style.css file

Note: My server is running but I am not able to use bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

You actually should add it to your `.angular.cli.json` list this

```
  "styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
```

Here is a source with more detail [Source](https://loiane.com/2017/08/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project/)

Comment: Is bootstrap in the node_modules directory? If you ran the install in a different location it could have been installed in a different directory. Make sure that it is present in `<projectroot>/node_modules/bootstrap`

Comment: Can you post your ‘.angular.cli.json’ file and your project file structure?