# Stylesheet not loaded because of MIME-type Angular application

Tags: html, css, angular, mime-types

I'm Working on a `Angular 6.x` application where i'm trying to change theme (dynamically).

The `CLI` compile everything properly but in `developer console`  im getting this error message.

> Refused to apply style from
>   'http://localhost:4200/vendor/theme-light.css' because its MIME type
>   ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME
>   checking is enabled.

My file structure looks like this, the path is correct

```
project
    |-src
      |-vendor
         |-theme-light.css
          |theme-dark.css
```

My theme changing code looks this

```
import { Component, Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT, isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

 @Component({
     ..
     ..
})

linkRef: HTMLLinkElement;

  themes = [
    { name: 'Light', href: '../vendor/theme-light.css' },
    { name: 'Dark', href: '../vendor/theme-dark.css' }
  ];

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document, @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      let theme = this.themes[0];
      try {
        const stored = localStorage.getItem('theme');
        if (stored) {
          theme = JSON.parse(stored);
        }
      } catch (e) {
      }
      this.linkRef = this.document.createElement('link');
      this.linkRef.rel = 'stylesheet';
      this.linkRef.href = theme.href;
      this.document.querySelector('head').appendChild(this.linkRef);
    }
  }

  setTheme(theme) {
    localStorage.setItem('theme', JSON.stringify(theme));
    this.linkRef.href = theme.href;
  }
```

Now, I don't really understand why this happens. Is am i missing something ? Feel free to ask for more details if needed.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you open http://localhost:4200/vendor/theme-light.css directly in your browser. Do you get a 404 error?

Comment: @SalmanA  thanks finally figured out what i'm i missing i  [posted the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53554317/7680307)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the href is wrong.

There is a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50668792/2342414) to a different question exactly like yours:

*The usual reason for this error message is that when the browser tries to load that resource, the server returns an HTML page instead, for example if your router catches unknown paths and displays a default page without a 404 error. Of course that means the path does not return the expected CSS file / image / icon / whatever...*

*The solution is to find the correct path and router configuration so that you get your plain CSS file / image / etc. when accessing that path.*

In your case it's the css href.

Comment: I tried to past the direct path of the file in browser and i'm getting plain css but not applying in browser

Comment: I think this is the right answer. Cf. my comment on your below answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53553463/6996150).

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured out Im giving the wrong path on my path configuration `href: '../vendor/theme-light.css'`  thats returns `http://localhost:4200/vendor/theme-light.css` on the browser which is not the correct path.

**Solution**

```
themes = [
    //added the missing src ( source root) 
    { name: 'Light', href: '../src/vendor/theme-light.css' },
    { name: 'Dark', href: '../src/vendor/theme-dark.css' }
  ];
```

Thank You for your answers

Answer (score 1):

when you're using a static folder , please make sure to use "/" . Let's say for example *assets* is our static folder , we want the image folder which is **under** the assets , so you type this src="image/img1.png" , that's wrong you have to add "/" ,,, so it will be like this  src="/image/img1.png"

Answer (score 0):

Found this answer here [Proper solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48270432/8179245)

The issue could be with a CSS library starting with comments. While on dev, We do not minify files and We don't remove comments, this meant that the stylesheet started with some comments, causing it to be seen as something different from css.

Removing the library and putting it into vendor file (which is ALWAYS minified without comments) solved the issue.

Comment: thank you for your answer but i've already tried that solution and no luck yet.

Comment: Can you share the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the place of your file css into the directory assets assets/style.css

and then put these path in your file index.html src/index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/style.css" />
```

in addition you have to modify to file angular.json in styles

```
"styles": [
          "src/assets/style.css",
          "./node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css",
        ],
```

Comment: "you have to change the place of your file css into the directory assets" Fair point @ricnef2121 but your solution didn't helping in what i'm trying to achieve here. Thank you