# css was not loaded because its MIME type in Meteor JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, node.js, meteor

I have meteor js 1.8 app, i have made a layout, and for that layout i want to add css. I have a structure like this:

imports

```
-ui
--stylesheets
--bootstrap.min.css
--font-awesome.min.css
--skins.css
--forms.css
```

So i have put all the css in `stylesheets` folder under imports. Now a layout called `main_layout.html' and corresponding`main_layout.js`and`main_layout.css` those files i put under:

```
-ui
--layouts
---dashboard
---main_layout.html
---main_layout.js
---main_layout.css
```

So i put all the imports in `main_layout.css` like this:

```
@import '{}/imports/ui/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css';
@import '{}/imports/ui/stylesheets/font-awesome.min.css';
@import '{}/imports/ui/stylesheets/skins.css';
@import '{}/imports/ui/stylesheets/forms.css';
```

And i imported `main_layout.css` in `main_layout.js` :

```
import './main_layout.html'
import './main_layout.css'
```

I have a rule for flow-router which renders this layout:

```
import '../../ui/layouts/dashboard/main_layout'

FlowRouter.route('/', {
    name: 'App.home',
    action() {
    BlazeLayout.render('mainLayout', {main: ''});
    },
});
```

But when i visit localhost:3000/ i get error in browser console:

The stylesheet http://localhost:3000/%7B%7D/imports/ui/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”.

And so on for the rest of css files. How can i load css using import then?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

The MIME type error message is just a symptom of your browser trying to fetch a CSS file that your server does not find and returns an HTML page instead. In the case of a Meteor app, a file not found is usually replaced by your main page.

See [Refused to apply style from '' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49406057/refused-to-apply-style-from-because-its-mime-type-text-html-is-not-a-supp/50668792?r=SearchResults#50668792)

In your specific case you just need to realize that `@import` in your CSS is not treated by your Meteor CSS package: it is copied as-is in your CSS rules. Therefore that is what your browser sees, and it requests the specified path. A simple workaround would be for example to place your vendor CSS in your project `public` folder, like a static asset, and continue importing it but with a corrected path like:

```css
@import '/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css';
```

(Assuming you placed the vendor file in `public/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css`)

You also have other possible solutions, typically importing each CSS file by referencing them in your JS file like you did for your entry CSS file, or using a different style compiling package which handles the imports (e.g. meteor sass).

Answer (score 0):

remove @ and use with . for public files,
like below:

```
import './stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css';
```