# Refused to execute script from '....' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: reactjs, webpack, mime

Hi I am new to React and recently built my app which was working fine locally but when my colleagues deployed it on the azure , we are facing this issue.

I tried looking for answers in stackoverflow itself but it was associated with changing webpack.config.js file which looks nothing like my config file which is in node_modules/react-scripts/config. So no idea how to solve it. Here is my public/index.html file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <title>Booking System</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems like your colleagues didn't configure azure correctly

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49406057/refused-to-apply-style-from-because-its-mime-type-text-html-is-not-a-supp/50668792#50668792